# How to find builds with a specific trigger

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to test the triggers I've setup for my new builds. 
Is there a way to query "the system" and find all builds that use a specific trigger?

```
select build_name where trigger like '/BRANCH/QA/%'
```

..and no i don't expect/need/care that it be sql interface... but you get the point

Comment: Did you look at the REST API documentation?

Comment: @DanielMann I'd have to know that it exist, thus asking (snippy attitude as I'm assuming you gave the down vote...otherwise I apologize). This dev was simply told "Your now in charge of your builds, use the others as an example" and the help feature in AzDevOps sends me here :)

Comment: Try to play with the builds rest api and update exactly where you stuck.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT yes it is. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to find builds with a specific trigger

To achieve this, you can use this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0):

Sample request:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?reasonFilter={reasonFilter}&api-version=5.0
```

Sample response:
    [image]

For the filter conditions of the query, you can refer to the **BuildReason** section of the document.

Hope this helps.